# jQuery display div on pageload depending on which radio button is checked

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery snippet that is hiding or displaying a div when a radio button is changed...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('input:radio[name="radiotype"]').change(
    function(){
        if (jQuery(this).val() == 'div1') {
          alert('div1 is selected');
            jQuery('.div1').css({'display':'block'});
            jQuery('.div2').css({'display':'none'});
        }
        else if (jQuery(this).val() == 'div2') {
         alert('div2 is selected');
            jQuery('.div1').css({'display':'none'});
            jQuery('.div2').css({'display':'block'});
        }
        else if (jQuery(this).val() == '') {
          alert('any is selected');
            jQuery('.div1').css({'display':'none'});
            jQuery('.div2').css({'display':'none'});            
        }

    })

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92tbLwrk/

It is working coprrectly when the radio button is changed but I would like it to change on page load depending on which radio button is checked.

Somebody suggested chaining to me but I am struggling to make it work with my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the change event to checked button after binding the event:

```
jQuery('input:radio[name="radiotype"]').change(function(){
   //your code
}).filter(':checked').change()
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Perfect, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MilindAnantwar nice +1